# How does this formula the formal definition of conditional expectation relate to a formula on the state space?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I'm using [Varadhan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0821828525) and when discussing the [formal definition of conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_sub-%CF%83-algebra) he gives a great formula. If $\phi(x, y)$ is the joint density of $X$ and $Y$ then:

$$E[f(X, Y) | X] = \frac{\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}{f(x, y)\phi(x,y)dy}}{\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}{\phi(x,y)dy}}$$

As a function of $x \in X^{-1}(\Omega)$ (where $\Omega$ is the state space), I get this - it essentially mirrors the "informal" definition of conditional expectation.

But, I'm not clear how this translates to a formula on $\Omega$. Technically, as I understand it, $E[f(X, Y)|X]$ is a $\sigma(X)$-measurable function from $\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $A \in \sigma(X)$ we get:

$$\int_{\omega \in A}{f(X(\omega),Y(\omega))d \mathbb{P}(\omega)} = \int_{\omega \in A}{E[f(X, Y) | X](\omega)d \mathbb{P}(\omega)}$$

But I'm having trouble connecting this last dot i.e. seeing $E[f(X, Y) | X]$ a funtion of $\Omega$ - especially considering that $X$ may not be injective. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $$E[f(X, Y) | X] = \frac{\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}{f(x, y)\phi(x,y)dy}}{\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}{\phi(x,y)dy}}$$ is abusing notation a bit.  What it really means is that $$E[f(X, Y) | X](\omega) = \frac{\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}{f(X(\omega), y)\phi(X(\omega),y)dy}}{\int_{y = -\infty}^{\infty}{\phi(X(\omega),y)dy}}.$$  In other words, the "$x$" in the formula stands for the value of $X$ at a given point $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: Makes sense. So, when I'm thinking of it in terms of a function on $x$  vs one of $\omega$ then $\phi(x, y) = \int_{\omega \in X^{-1}(x)}{\phi(\omega, y) d \mathbb{P}(\omega)}$, right?

Comment: No, that equation doesn't make sense.  (For one thing, $X^{-1}(x)$ will typically have measure $0$ so the right-hand side would just be $0$.)  The density function is inherently a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, because it is all about Lebesgue measure.  It is the function that relates Lebesgue measure to the pushforward of $\mathbb{P}$ along the map $(X,Y):\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks.